# Is it possible to deserialize XML into List<T>?

Tags: c#, serialization, xml-serialization, xml-deserialization

Given the following XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<user_list>
   <user>
      <id>1</id>
      <name>Joe</name>
   </user>
   <user>
      <id>2</id>
      <name>John</name>
   </user>
</user_list>
```

And the following class:

```
public class User {
   [XmlElement("id")]
   public Int32 Id { get; set; }

   [XmlElement("name")]
   public String Name { get; set; }
}
```

Is it possible to use `XmlSerializer` to deserialize the xml into a `List<User>` ? If so, what type of additional attributes will I need to use, or what additional parameters do I need to use to construct the `XmlSerializer` instance?

An array ( `User[]` ) would be acceptable, if a bit less preferable.

Answer (score 155, accepted):

You can *encapsulate* the list trivially:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Xml.Serialization;

[XmlRoot("user_list")]
public class UserList
{
    public UserList() {Items = new List<User>();}
    [XmlElement("user")]
    public List<User> Items {get;set;}
}
public class User
{
    [XmlElement("id")]
    public Int32 Id { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("name")]
    public String Name { get; set; }
}

static class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        XmlSerializer ser= new XmlSerializer(typeof(UserList));
        UserList list = new UserList();
        list.Items.Add(new User { Id = 1, Name = "abc"});
        list.Items.Add(new User { Id = 2, Name = "def"});
        list.Items.Add(new User { Id = 3, Name = "ghi"});
        ser.Serialize(Console.Out, list);
    }
}
```

Comment: Nice solution with the [XmlElement("user")] to avoid an extra level of elements.  Looking at this, I thought for sure that it would have emitted a <user> or <Items> node (if you did not have the XmlElement attribute), and then add <user> nodes under that.  But I tried it and it did not, thus emitting exactly what the question wanted.

Comment: What if I had two lists under UserList above? I tried your method and it says it already defines a member called XYZ with the same parameter types

Comment: I don't know why this is marked as right answer.  It includes adding a class to wrap the list.   That was certainly what the question is trying to avoid.

Comment: @DDRider62 the question doesn't say "without wrapping". Most people are pretty pragmatic and just want to get the data out. This answer allows you to do that, via the `.Items` member.

Answer (score 61):

If you decorate the `User` class with the `XmlType` to match the required capitalization:

```
[XmlType("user")]
public class User
{
   ...
}
```

Then the `XmlRootAttribute` on the `XmlSerializer` ctor can provide the desired root and allow direct reading into List<>:

```
    // e.g. my test to create a file
    using (var writer = new FileStream("users.xml", FileMode.Create))
    {
        XmlSerializer ser = new XmlSerializer(typeof(List<User>),  
            new XmlRootAttribute("user_list"));
        List<User> list = new List<User>();
        list.Add(new User { Id = 1, Name = "Joe" });
        list.Add(new User { Id = 2, Name = "John" });
        list.Add(new User { Id = 3, Name = "June" });
        ser.Serialize(writer, list);
    }
```

...

```
    // read file
    List<User> users;
    using (var reader = new StreamReader("users.xml"))
    {
        XmlSerializer deserializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(List<User>),  
            new XmlRootAttribute("user_list"));
        users = (List<User>)deserializer.Deserialize(reader);
    }
```

Credit: based on [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21775195/451944) from [YK1](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1529246/yk1).

Comment: In my point of view, this is clearly THE answer to the question.   The question was about deserializing into List<T>.  All the other solutions, except maybe one, include a wrapping class to contain the list, which was certainly not the question posted, and what the author of the question seems to be trying to avoid.

Comment: With this approach, the `XmlSerializer` must be statically cached and reused to avoid a severe memory leak, see [Memory Leak using StreamReader and XmlSerializer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23897145/3744182) for details.

Answer (score 18):

Yes, it will serialize and deserialize a List<>. Just make sure you use the [XmlArray] attribute if in doubt.

```
[Serializable]
public class A
{
    [XmlArray]
    public List<string> strings;
}
```

This works with both Serialize() and Deserialize().

Comment: That's the magic piece I was missing

Answer (score 15):

I think I have found a better way. You don't have to put attributes into your classes. I've made two methods for serialization and deserialization which take generic list as parameter.

Take a look (it works for me):

```
private void SerializeParams<T>(XDocument doc, List<T> paramList)
    {
        System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer serializer = new System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer(paramList.GetType());

        System.Xml.XmlWriter writer = doc.CreateWriter();

        serializer.Serialize(writer, paramList);

        writer.Close();           
    }

private List<T> DeserializeParams<T>(XDocument doc)
    {
        System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer serializer = new System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer(typeof(List<T>));

        System.Xml.XmlReader reader = doc.CreateReader();

        List<T> result = (List<T>)serializer.Deserialize(reader);
        reader.Close();

        return result;
    }
```

So you can serialize whatever list you want! You don't need to specify the list type every time.

```
        List<AssemblyBO> list = new List<AssemblyBO>();
        list.Add(new AssemblyBO());
        list.Add(new AssemblyBO() { DisplayName = "Try", Identifier = "243242" });
        XDocument doc = new XDocument();
        SerializeParams<T>(doc, list);
        List<AssemblyBO> newList = DeserializeParams<AssemblyBO>(doc);
```

Comment: Thanks for actually answering the question. I would add that for `List<MyClass>` the document element should be named `ArrayOfMyClass`.

Answer (score 9):

Yes, it does deserialize to List<>. No need to keep it in an array and wrap/encapsulate it in a list.

```
public class UserHolder
{
    private List<User> users = null;

    public UserHolder()
    {
    }

    [XmlElement("user")]
    public List<User> Users
    {
        get { return users; }
        set { users = value; }
    }
}
```

Deserializing code,

```
XmlSerializer xs = new XmlSerializer(typeof(UserHolder));
UserHolder uh = (UserHolder)xs.Deserialize(new StringReader(str));
```

Answer (score 5):

Not sure about List<T> but Arrays are certainly do-able.  And a little bit of magic makes it really easy to get to a List again.

```
public class UserHolder {
   [XmlElement("list")]
   public User[] Users { get; set; }

   [XmlIgnore]
   public List<User> UserList { get { return new List<User>(Users); } }
}
```

Comment: Is it possible to do without the "holder" class?

Comment: @Daniel, AFAIK, no.  You need to serialize and deserialize into some concrete object type.  I do not believe that XML serialization natively supports collection classes as the start of a serialization.  I do not 100% know that though.

Comment: [XmlElement("list")] should be [XmlArray("list")] instead. That is the only way Deserialization worked for me in .NET 4.5

Answer (score 2):

How about

```
XmlSerializer xs = new XmlSerializer(typeof(user[]));
using (Stream ins = File.Open(@"c:\some.xml", FileMode.Open))
foreach (user o in (user[])xs.Deserialize(ins))
   userList.Add(o);
```

Not particularly fancy but it should work.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow! It's always better to provide a short description for a sample code to improve the post accuracy :)

Answer (score -1):

Yes, you can deserialize into `List<User>` or `User[]` with the `XmlSerializer`. I would prefer `List<User>` over `User[]`. Note that `XmlSerializer` does not support deserialization into interfaces, so you cannot deserialize into `ICollection<T>`, `IReadOnlyCollection<T>` or `IList<T>` as this will fail with a `NotSupportedException`.