# Binding arbitrary XML to a datagrid

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-4.0

I'm completely new at silverlight, and trying to do things "the right way".

Problem is: I have an XML that I need to get from a web server, and I need to display that data in a datagrid.

I've searched around and I've managed to get the following:

say my XML looks like:

```
<customers>
    <customer>
        <name>A Person</name>
        <address>my address</address>
    </customer>
    <customer>
        <name>A Guy</name>
        <address>my address 2</address>
    </customer>
</customers>
```

I can retrieve this and populate a POCO such as:

```
public class Customer
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public string Address { get; set; }
}
...
XDocument oDoc = //read from a string asnychronously
var myData = from info in oDoc.Descendants("customer")
    select new Customer
    {
        Name = Convert.ToString(info.Element("name").Value),
        Address = Convert.ToString(info.Element("address").Value
    };
_grid.ItemsSource = myData;
```

However, if I take this approach, I won't really be using Silverlight's dynamic binding capabilities.

How can I do this in the "Silverlight" way so that when I (or someone else who actually knows silverlight) look at the code a few years down the line, don't hate absolutely hate what I've done.

Comment: I'm not sure what you imagine "dynamic binding" is but Silverlight relies heavily on reflecting over types for its binding.  Hence you need a type such as your `Customer` object in order for Silverlight to bind effectively.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at using the [XMLSerializer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlserializer%28VS.95%29.aspx).[Deserialize](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dsh84875.aspx) method to de-serialize your XML automatically without having to deal with XDocument. Your class will look like this:

```
[XmlRoot]
public class Customer
{
    [XmlElement]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [XmlElement]
    public string Address { get; set; }

}
```

Once you have the data de-serialized, take a look at [MVVM](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd458800.aspx) on how to properly bind the data to your views.

Comment: However, doing the above for the Customer class doesn't "automatically" give you an IEnumerable<Customer>.

Comment: Yes, of course, there are a couple of steps you have to go through: Create a serializer and pass the source of the data to de-serialize. However, this is a more maintainable way of doing it as adding or removing properties or even entire classes does not require you to update the de-serialization code, just the classes and attributes. I will try to add some more detail to the answer later, to make this clearer.

Comment: I had taken a look at that MVVM how-to, I just missed a few bits that are not really explicit unless you download the full code to ill in the missing parts.

Thanks a lot for the pointers anyhow, its good to get knowledge of other things you get "for free".

Comment: For anyone interested, Mark Gravell's answer on  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/608110/is-it-possible-to-deserialize-xml-into-listt clearly shows how to implement the list of nodes.