# Deserialization XMl Error

Tags: c#, xml, xml-deserialization

The serialization of a list doesn't face problems. Creation of the XML File:

```
        XmlDocument toolConfig = new XmlDocument();
        XmlNode myRoot;
        myRoot = toolConfig.CreateElement("Tool");
        toolConfig.AppendChild(myRoot);           
        toolConfig.Save(@userConfigurePath + "\\config.xml");
```

After the serialization the xml file looks like this:

```
     <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
     <Tools xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
     xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
     <Tool>
       <Name>test</Name>
       <Path>C:\Program Files\FreePDF_XP\freepdf.exe</Path>
     </Tool>
     <Tool>
      <Name>test2</Name>
      <Path>C:\Program Files\FreePDF_XP\fpconfig.exe</Path>
    </Tool>
    <Tool>
      <Name>test3</Name>
      <Path>C:\Program Files\FreePDF_XP\redrun.exe</Path>
    </Tool>
</Tools>
```

Deserialization code:

```
    private void ToolHandling_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {

        XmlSerializer deserializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(List<Tool>));

        using (var reader = new StreamReader(@Start.userConfigurePath + 
        "\\config.xml"))
        {
            toolList = (List<Tool>)deserializer.Deserialize(reader);
            reader.Close();
        }
```

I get the XML Document Error 2,2 : System.InvalidOperationException: There is an error in XML document (2, 2). Therefore I used a validation tool for the document and I got no error . Where is the source of the error?

Edit: Full code to compose the xml:

```
 private List<Tool> toolList = new List<Tool>();
 private void ToolHandling_Closed(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(toolList.GetType(), new  
        XmlRootAttribute("Tools"));
        using (var writer = new StreamWriter(@Start.userConfigurePath + 
       "\\config.xml")) 
        {
            serializer.Serialize(writer, toolList);
            writer.Close();
         }
        }
```

Comment: Can you show full code for compose your xml?

Comment: Added at the main post =)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You forgot to specify root attribute while de-serializing:

```
XmlSerializer deserializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(List<Tool>) , new XmlRootAttribute("Tools"));
```

Answer (score 1):

You could wrap the List in a simple container, then deserialize this.

```
[XmlRoot("Tools")]
public class ToolList
{
    public ToolList() { Items = new List<Tool>(); }
    [XmlElement("Tool")]
    public List<Tool> Items;
}

private void ToolHandling_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{

    XmlSerializer deserializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(ToolList));

    using (var reader = new StreamReader(@Start.userConfigurePath + 
    "\\config.xml"))
    {
    toolList = (ToolList)deserializer.Deserialize(reader);
    reader.Close();
    }
}
```

Based on [source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/608110/is-it-possible-to-deserialize-xml-into-listt).

Comment: ... but you're right to accept YK1's simpler answer! :) [ref](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f1wczcys(v=vs.110).aspx).

Answer (score 0):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlserializer(v=vs.110).aspx

Serialization of ArrayList and Generic List
**The XmlSerializer cannot serialize or deserialize the following:**
Arrays of `ArrayList`
Arrays of `List<T>`

I think you can use LINQ to XML for solve this task.

Comment: with the serialization there aren't problems