# How can I display IEnumerable<XElement> type in GridView?

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, xelement

I need to retrieve data from an `XML` file then display this result set in `GridView` by using `LINQ`.

I have read the `XML` file from disk and fetched the elements I want, but I need to display these results in table. What should I do?

C# code:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        XElement xml = XElement.Load(@"C:\veri.xml");
        IEnumerable<XElement> urunler = xml.Elements("urun");
    }
```

My xml schema :

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" elementFormDefault="qualified">
    <xs:element name="root">
    <xs:complexType>
     <xs:sequence>
     <xs:element maxOccurs="unbounded" ref="urun"/>
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
  <xs:element name="urun">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element ref="urunid"/>
        <xs:element ref="urunkodu"/>
        <xs:element ref="urunadi"/>
        <xs:element ref="urunlink"/>
        <xs:element ref="urundetay"/>
        <xs:element ref="marka"/>
        <xs:element ref="urunkategori"/>
        <xs:element ref="kategorinav"/>
        <xs:element ref="resimler"/>
        <xs:element ref="fiyat"/>
        <xs:element ref="toplamstok"/>
        <xs:element ref="stokbilgileri"/>
        <xs:element ref="ozellikler"/>
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
  <xs:element name="urunid" type="xs:integer"/>
  <xs:element name="urunkodu" type="xs:string"/>
  <xs:element name="urunadi" type="xs:string"/>
  <xs:element name="urunlink" type="xs:anyURI"/>
  <xs:element name="urundetay" type="xs:string"/>
  <xs:element name="marka">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element ref="markaadi"/>
        <xs:element ref="markaid"/>
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
  <xs:element name="markaadi" type="xs:string"/>
  <xs:element name="markaid" type="xs:integer"/>
  <xs:element name="urunkategori">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element ref="kategoriadi"/>
        <xs:element ref="kategoriid"/>
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
  <xs:element name="kategoriadi" type="xs:string"/>
  <xs:element name="kategoriid" type="xs:integer"/>
  <xs:element name="kategorinav">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element maxOccurs="unbounded" ref="kategori"/>
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
  <xs:element name="kategori" type="xs:string"/>
  <xs:element name="resimler">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element maxOccurs="unbounded" ref="resim"/>
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
  <xs:element name="resim" type="xs:anyURI"/>
  <xs:element name="fiyat">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element ref="kdvoran"/>
        <xs:element ref="bayifiyat"/>
        <xs:element ref="bayifiyatkdvli"/>
        <xs:element ref="perakendefiyat"/>
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
  <xs:element name="kdvoran" type="xs:integer"/>
  <xs:element name="bayifiyat" type="xs:string"/>
  <xs:element name="bayifiyatkdvli" type="xs:string"/>
  <xs:element name="perakendefiyat" type="xs:string"/>
  <xs:element name="toplamstok" type="xs:integer"/>
  <xs:element name="stokbilgileri">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element maxOccurs="unbounded" ref="stokkayit"/>
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
  <xs:element name="stokkayit">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element ref="renk"/>
        <xs:element ref="beden"/>
        <xs:element ref="stokadet"/>
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
  <xs:element name="renk" type="xs:string"/>
  <xs:element name="beden" type="xs:NMTOKEN"/>
  <xs:element name="stokadet" type="xs:integer"/>
  <xs:element name="ozellikler">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element ref="aynigunkargo"/>
        <xs:element ref="hizligonderi"/>
        <xs:element ref="onsiparisliurun"/>
        <xs:element ref="sinirlistok"/>
        <xs:element ref="ucretsizkargo"/>
        <xs:element ref="stoksorunuz"/>
        <xs:element ref="desi"/>
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
  <xs:element name="aynigunkargo" type="xs:NCName"/>
  <xs:element name="hizligonderi" type="xs:NCName"/>
  <xs:element name="onsiparisliurun" type="xs:NCName"/>
  <xs:element name="sinirlistok" type="xs:NCName"/>
  <xs:element name="ucretsizkargo" type="xs:NCName"/>
  <xs:element name="stoksorunuz" type="xs:NCName"/>
  <xs:element name="desi" type="xs:integer"/>
</xs:schema>
```

Comment: can you show your xml product schema ?

Comment: Did you try to use `XmlSerializer` for deserializing xml to an object  ? as herein :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/608110/is-it-possible-to-deserialize-xml-into-listt