# Convert XML Document to classes

Tags: c#, xml

I have the following xml document that is from a 3 party and saved in a database.  I am trying to figure out the best way take the document and load classes so I can manipulate the data and then save it to the database in tables that closely representing the class.

```
<Payroll xmlns:dtv="http://www.datavantagecorp.com/xstore/"><dtv:Payroll>
<dtv:StartDate>2015-02-08</dtv:StartDate>
<dtv:EndDate>2015-02-14</dtv:EndDate>
<dtv:PostedDate>2015-02-16</dtv:PostedDate>
<dtv:Employee EmployeeId="111122">
<dtv:EmployeePayStatus></dtv:EmployeePayStatus>
<dtv:PayrollStoreNumber>8009</dtv:PayrollStoreNumber>
<dtv:ReviewedDate></dtv:ReviewedDate>
<dtv:PayrollCategory Category="OT">
<dtv:PayrollDate>2015-02-14</dtv:PayrollDate>
<dtv:Hours>0.53</dtv:Hours>
<dtv:PayrollDate>2015-02-12</dtv:PayrollDate>
<dtv:Hours>0.77</dtv:Hours>
<dtv:PayrollDate>2015-02-11</dtv:PayrollDate>
<dtv:Hours>0.13</dtv:Hours>
<dtv:PayrollDate>2015-02-09</dtv:PayrollDate>
<dtv:Hours>0.12</dtv:Hours>
</dtv:PayrollCategory>
<dtv:PayrollCategory Category="DT">
</dtv:PayrollCategory>
<dtv:PayrollCategory Category="REGULAR">
<dtv:PayrollDate>2015-02-09</dtv:PayrollDate>
<dtv:Hours>8.00</dtv:Hours>
<dtv:WorkCode code="888">
<dtv:TotalHours>8.12</dtv:TotalHours>
</dtv:WorkCode>
<dtv:PayrollDate>2015-02-10</dtv:PayrollDate>
<dtv:Hours>6.03</dtv:Hours>
<dtv:WorkCode code="888">
<dtv:TotalHours>6.03</dtv:TotalHours>
</dtv:WorkCode>
<dtv:PayrollDate>2015-02-11</dtv:PayrollDate>
<dtv:Hours>8.00</dtv:Hours>
<dtv:WorkCode code="888">
<dtv:TotalHours>8.13</dtv:TotalHours>
</dtv:WorkCode>
<dtv:PayrollDate>2015-02-12</dtv:PayrollDate>
<dtv:Hours>8.00</dtv:Hours>
<dtv:WorkCode code="888">
<dtv:TotalHours>8.77</dtv:TotalHours>
</dtv:WorkCode>
<dtv:PayrollDate>2015-02-13</dtv:PayrollDate>
<dtv:Hours>6.81</dtv:Hours>
<dtv:WorkCode code="888">
<dtv:TotalHours>6.81</dtv:TotalHours>
</dtv:WorkCode>
<dtv:PayrollDate>2015-02-14</dtv:PayrollDate>
<dtv:Hours>3.16</dtv:Hours>
<dtv:WorkCode code="888">
<dtv:TotalHours>3.69</dtv:TotalHours>
</dtv:WorkCode>
</dtv:PayrollCategory>
<dtv:PayrollCategory Category="SICK">
</dtv:PayrollCategory>
<dtv:PayrollCategory Category="VACATION">
</dtv:PayrollCategory>
<dtv:PayrollCategory Category="HOLIDAY">
</dtv:PayrollCategory>
<dtv:PayrollCategory Category="RT">
</dtv:PayrollCategory>
<dtv:PayrollCategory Category="EO">
</dtv:PayrollCategory>
<dtv:PayrollCategory Category="RSA">
</dtv:PayrollCategory>
</dtv:Employee>
</dtv:Payroll>
</Payroll>
```

The XML can have several Employees within a Payroll.  I was thinking I would have the following classes:

Payroll
Employee
PayrollCategory

where for each Payroll, there is a list of employees and each employee has a list of PayrollCategory.  I have started heading down the following path but not sure if this is the best way or if there is a better solution.

```
                foreach (DataRow row in ds.Tables[0].Rows)
                {
                    var doc = new XmlDocument();
                    doc.LoadXml(row[0].ToString());
                }
```

Any suggestions or links on how to go out handling this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fa420a9y(v=vs.110).aspx XML deserialization is standard practice. Please follow the link.

Comment: Open your VS. `Edit =>Paste Special=>Paste XML as classes`. Then search for XmlSerializer.

Comment: Look into [Entity Framework](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/ef.aspx).  It's an ORM (Object-Relational Mapping) framework, which means it maps objects to a relational database.

Comment: Entity Framework is not an option for me.  It is not a standard for my company.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend creating classes for your XML elements, that you can serialize/deserialize from the XML document. There's a few questions and answers on how to do that (such as the one found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/608110/is-it-possible-to-deserialize-xml-into-listt)).

If you have an XSD Schema for your XML Document, you could probably even autogenerate the classes.

Answer (score -2):

```
foreach (var row in ds.Tables[0].Rows)
{
    var doc = XDocument.Load(new MemoryStream(new UTF8Encoding().GetBytes(row[0])));
}
```

Comment: Downvoting without a stated reason is about as useless as tits on a boar hog. XDocument is a class, and if he needs to get at the contained data he can use Linq to easily query it out.

Comment: I downvoted, OP asked for a way to get objects out of the XmlDocument and I didn't think your answer helped. Your comment about using LINQ on the XDocument however does help. I think you should edit your answer to include this - and then I'll remove the downvote :)
Still, OP won't get actual classes out of this solution, but it could solve the ultimate goal of mapping XML to database tables.

Comment: And furthermore - didn't dv - answer containing only code is rather useless. You should explain what happens and why it works.