# deserialize XML file into a list error

Tags: c#, xml, list, serialization

i writed the follow generic code to deserialize an XML file into a list:

```
public List<T> getList<T>(string fPath)
{

    FileStream fs;
    fs = new FileStream(fPath, FileMode.Open);
    List<T> list;
    XmlSerializer xmls = new XmlSerializer(typeof(List<T>));
    list = (List<T>)xmls.Deserialize(fs);
    fs.Close();
    return list;
}
```

but i got the the Exception on the desirialize action.

> "An exception of type `System.InvalidOperationException` occurred in System.Xml.dll but was not handled in user code"

this is an example for the XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<ArrayOfAdmin xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"    xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <Admin>
    <MyUsername>User</MyUsername>
    <MyPassword>Pass</MyPassword>
  </Admin>
</ArrayOfAdmin>
```

whats cause the Exception?

Comment: Can you update your post to include a small XML file you would expect to be able to deserialize?

Comment: Hello Sefeli please check in this question : [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/608110/is-it-possible-to-deserialize-xml-into-listt](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/608110/is-it-possible-to-deserialize-xml-into-listt)

Comment: An XML file can only have a single Root Tag so it cannot be a collection.  You want to deserialize the root which is tag "ArrayOfAdmin" not the child tag Admin.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, your file should contain valid xml data with serialized `List<T>` object. E.g. if you have serialized list of integers with items 1 and 2 xml should look this way:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<ArrayOfInt xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
            xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <int>1</int>
  <int>2</int>
</ArrayOfInt>
```

Or with your custom type:

```
<ArrayOfPerson xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
               xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <Person>
    <Id>1</Id>
    <Name>Bob</Name>
  </Person>
  <Person>
    <Id>2</Id>
    <Name>Joe</Name>
  </Person>
</ArrayOfPerson>
```

When file is empty or it has invalid data you will get `InvalidOperationException` during deserialization attempt. Read property `Message` of this exception to get some details. E.g. if file is empty, it will say that root element is missing.

NOTE: When you are working with unmanaged resources it's better to use `using` construct to close/dispose such resources correctly in case of exception.

```
using (var stream = File.Open(fPath, FileMode.Open))
{
    var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(List<T>));
    return (List<T>)serializer.Deserialize(stream);
}
```